# How can I listen to free radio on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, applications, iphone

Is it possible to listen to the radio for free on the iPhone?

Do I need a special app?

I have downloaded some apps for digital radio that require payment, but I just want to listen to regular free radio

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to normal, terrestrial radio such as you'd get in your car or a cheap clock radio, the answer is that you cannot. At least, not without buying a receiver, something like [this Griffin radio receiver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ERT46W).

Comment: Apologies, I approved your edit after the question had already been migrated because I checked in the wrong order. I have however edited this one already.

Comment: And your edit is approved.

Answer (score 1):

There are radio apps in the iPhone app store that will give you radio stations in your area and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of stating the obvious, you can listen to Pandora—*internet* radio—for free on your iPhone.  And for a small fee you can listen without advertisements.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good radio app called [Tunein Radio Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tunein-radio/id319295332?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) which allows you to listen to over 50,000 radio stations across the world and which is cheap to buy, $0.99 in the US.  There's also a [non-Pro version](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tunein-radio/id418987775?mt=8) which is free.